# How to stop SVG animateMotion on hover?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, css-animations

I am using a path:

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 400 400" xml:space="preserve">
<g class="path path--1">
    <path class="path_layer" id="path1" d="M200,240c-80,0 -80,-80 0,-80c80,0 80,80 0,80" stroke="#333333" stroke-width="2" fill="none"/>
</g>
<circle r="5" fill="white" id="planet">
        <title>Computer Science</title>
        <animateMotion dur="15s" repeatCount="indefinite" keyPoints="0.5;0;1;0.5" keyTimes="0;0.5;0.5;1" calcMode="linear">
            <mpath xlink:href="#path1" /> 
        </animateMotion>
</circle>
```

along which I will be animating the circle as shown above.

Now, I would like to stop the animation on hover, any idea how to do this?
When I hover on the circle, I want to stop the animation and later resume it from wherever I stopped it. The CSS way  does not work for this. Should I use JS, if so, how?

Comment: No, this is an SVG, SVG's elements cannot be controlled using the answer given.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the SVG DOM to pause and unpause the animation timeline. The [`<svg>` element's interface](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/struct.html#InterfaceSVGSVGElement) has the following useful methods:

```
pauseAnimations(); // pauses the SMIL animation
unpauseAnimations(); // resumes the SMIL animation

setCurrentTime(); // changes the timeline thereby allowing you to rerun an animation
```

Comment: If I have multiple circles animating, this will stop all of them, could you point me on how to avoid that?

Comment: You could try putting them in separate documents via iframe or object tags. Other alternatives such as recording the animation state and then deleting and recreating the animation would be harder but not impossible.